# Retrieve a list of Cases from Accounts SOQL

Tags: soql, case, query, account

I am trying to get a list of all Accounts with their related Cases. There is a lookup on the Case object to Account (AccountId). Right now I have to do two queries:

```
    List<Account> stores = [
        SELECT Account.Name
        FROM Account 
        WHERE Account.Id IN (SELECT Case.accountId FROM Case)];

List<Case> predictions = [
    SELECT Id, AccountId, CaseNumber
    FROM Case
    WHERE AccountId = :stores.get(i)
];
```

Is there anyway to do a nested SELECT in the Accounts query?
I'm horrible with inner/outer joins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine your two queries into one like:

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Id, AccountId, CaseNumber FROM Cases) FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case)
```

Alternative would be to query for the Cases and related Account data like:

```
SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, CaseNumber FROM Case WHERE AccountId != ''
```

The Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference pdf, found [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf), is a great resource!

Adding an image from the developer console from the first query:
[image: Developer Console Query]

Comment: When trying the first option, I don't see the Case information in my response (Id, AccountId, CaseNumber). All I get back is the Name (account) and Id (account).

Comment: @AustinNelson - Ok weird...I see the same thing **BUT** if you add a limit statement to the subquery `From Cases Limit 10` it works....Or if you add a selective Where Clause

Comment: Sorry, I edited the wrong post

Comment: `[SELECT Name,
              (SELECT Id, AccountId, CaseNumber From Cases LIMIT 10) 
             FROM Account 
             WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Case)]`

Still doesn't return any Cases. I've even tried on a specific Account:

`WHERE Id = ''`

And couldn't get any Cases back

Comment: @AustinNelson attaching an image of the query from my dev org.  Assuming you have data where cases are related to the account? What do you get back on the second query?

Comment: @JennyB I was running the query in the Execute Anonymous window instead of the Query Editor. In Code, how would I reference the CaseNumber? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @AustinNelson if you loop through the accounts then you can have an inner loop for the cases to access each individual case and it's fields.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

If you have a list of Account IDs say `Set<ID> acctIDs`

```
[Select Name, ID, (Select ID, CaseNumber From Cases) From Account Where ID = :acctIDs];
```

**Update**: As of 9-2-2015 The above always returns 0 records for cases. **BUT** if you add a LIMIT clause records are returned **OR** if you add a selective where clause, records are returned. Not sure if it is a bug or by design

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately I still don't get back any Case information, just Account information.

Comment: @AustinNelson - Ok weird...I see the same thing BUT if you add a limit statement to the subquery From Cases Limit 10 it works....Or if you add a selective Where Clause